# $http.post and TypeScript accessors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am writing an AngularJS app (v1.3.15) using TypeScript 1.5 in Visual Studio 2013. I have run across a problem with TypeScript object properties/accessors and JSON serialization using $http.post(). My AngularJS is pretty solid I think but I am quite new to TypeScript.

My TypeScript class looks like this:

```
module Wizard.Models {
    import Address = Wizard.Models.Address;
    "use strict";

    export class YourDetailsModel {
        public useSecondaryAsPrimary: boolean;

        private _primaryFirstName: string;
        private _primaryLastName: string;
        private _primaryAddressModel: Address = new Models.Address();

        get primaryFirstName(): string {
            return !this.useSecondaryAsPrimary ? this._primaryFirstName : this.SecondaryFirstName;
        }

        set primaryFirstName(primaryFirstName: string) {
            this._primaryFirstName = primaryFirstName;
        }

        get primaryLastName(): string {
            return !this.useSecondaryAsPrimary ? this._primaryLastName : this.SecondaryLastName;
        }

        set primaryLastName(primaryLastName: string) {
            this._primaryLastName = primaryLastName;
        }

        get primaryAddressModel(): Address {
            return !this.useSecondaryAsPrimary ? this._primaryAddressModel : this.SecondaryAddressModel;
        }

        set primaryAddressModel(primaryAddressModel: Address) {
            this._primaryAddressModel = primaryAddressModel;
        }

        public SecondaryFirstName: string;
        public SecondaryLastName: string;
        public SecondaryAddressModel: Address = new Models.Address();
    }
}
```

My intention is that when the object is serialized, all the public members and properties via accessors should be serialized, and the private properties should not. The current behaviour is that some of the *private* members are being serialized whereas some of the public members are not.

Is this asking too much? There are other ways for me to achieve this so it's not the end of the world if I can't get it working. I don't actually need to fiddle with the model class in this way.

But it's the most elegant way of keeping the model playing its cards close to its chest, so to speak.

Any help appreciated. M.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this asking too much? There are other ways for me to achieve this so it's not the end of the world if I can't get it working. I don't actually need to fiddle with the model class in this way

There is *no runtime difference* between a `private` and a `public` member. That is to say that the JavaScript emitted for each is *exactly the same*.

I suggest using a variable naming convention on top of `private/public` e.g. `public foo` and `private _foo`. Then during serialization you can check if a property name starts with `_`.

Comment: I'm going to refactor and do this elsewhere. Where it ought to be done. Thanks for your input though.